# Why does Hutter alone survive the vampire bite?

Tags: plot-explanation, nosferatu

In the German silent film [*Nosferatu* (1922)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0013442/), the vampire *Count Orlok* bites the guy *Hutter*.

But then how come he alone survives while all the other people who have been bitten by that vampire die?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any real reason for this, other than the fact it helps the story along.

Hutter doesn't know who Orlok is. When eating dinner at Orlok's mansion, he cuts his thumb and is nearly devoured by Orlok who wants his blood. He then wakes up the following morning with two puncture wounds in his neck.

Given Orlok easily kills many people later in the same way, the only logical explanation is that, for whatever reason, he wanted to keep Hutter alive - whether permanently or temporarily, we don't know.

I suspect this wasn't given too much thought when creating the movie, as it proved to be a useful plot device building the audience up to understand the terrible truth of who Count Orlok *really* was.

Comment: While I haven't seen *Murnau*'s version yet (and am thus unable to judge this question or its answers), if it follows *Stoker*'s original, the *Count* had enough reasons for *Hutter* to stay alive, I think, seeing that he needed him as realtor and maybe as a future servant similar to *Renfield* (or however he was called in this version, if even existent).

Comment: I think that the realtor argument is definitely the most likely.